Kotlin mapper.readValue with missing filed
In my data class I have
data class Example(
    val purchaseId: String,
    val customerId: String,
    val purchaseDate: Long
)

when mapping a payload to Example I have
val expectedValue = "{\"purchaseId\":\"5005d000023FqKXAA0\",\"customerId\":\"10065416831\",\"purchaseDate\":1687523394\"}"

val result = mapper.readValue(expectedValue, Example::class.java)

so when expectedValue has all the properties, expectedValue gets mapped to Example without any problem.
But when expectedValue is missing purchaseId or another field like
val expectedValue = "{\"customerId\":\"10065416831\",\"purchaseDate\":1687523394\"}"

I get
Instantiation of [simple type, class Example] value failed for JSON property purchaseId due to missing (therefore NULL) value for creator parameter caseId which is a non-nullable type

without making Example fields nullable, is there a way I can validate if the expected payload has the properties I care about?

is it an ObjectMapper / jackson ?

Yes ObjectMapper

Ypu need to initialize your ObjectMapper in the following way:
val mapper = ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

what you are looking for is the FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES configuration property.
